# Official name for "symmetric percent difference" function (x-y)/max(x,y)

Tags: group-differences

I frequently use this formula to compare two positive numbers $x$ and $y$ to see if they are "more different" than some threshold:

$$
x-y \over \max(x,y)
$$

It is nice because it is symmetric and bounded to $[-1,1]$ (unlike relative percent difference). I call it a "symmetric percent difference." I see a similar formula on [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_difference#Formulas), apparently generalized to negative or positive numbers, but it's not named:

$$
|x-y| \over \max(|x|,|y|)
$$

Does anyone know the official name for this function?

Note: Another similar function, bounded to $[0,1]$, is used to calculate sMAPE:

$$
|x-y| \over x+y
$$

Comment: What would make a name 'official'?

Comment: I'd be happy with a citation of any named usage, bonus if it's a scholarly article or textbook. But possibly the formula is not used frequently enough to be named.

Comment: Any? Okay, well [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74705/official-name-for-symmetric-percent-difference-function-x-y-maxx-y) it's called a 'symmetric percent difference'. But that term seems to mean different things in [other places](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11113946). To be honest, I don't think there's going to be a widely used name for it.

Comment: @Glen_b, I guess then I'm an official source now :). Yes, I saw a few other things referred to by this name when I was googling around. I think the name best describes my formula though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last function you mention is the [coefficient of variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) (standard deviation over mean) of a sample of just two values:

$$c_v = \frac {\sigma}{\mu}$$
and when we have only two values, $\sigma = |x-y|/2$ while $\mu = (x+y)/2$.

As for your function, although by not using absolute value in the numerator you hint that direction may be important to you, I expect usually subtracting the smallest from the largest value.
Then, since our sample is only these two numbers essentially we have

$$\frac {\text {range}}{\max} = \frac {\max - \min}{\max} = 1- \frac {\min}{\max}$$

Now the $\frac {max}{min}$ ratio is encountered in various situations, check for example, "dynamic range" or "contrast ratio".

On a more mundane level, if $x$ is "final price"$=p_f$ and $y$ is "list price"$=p_l$, then

$$\frac {x-y} {\max(x,y)} = \frac {p_f -p_l}{p_l} $$

equals the "percentage discount" -with the negative sign to indicate the direction of revenues!

Comment: Yes, direction is often important. Answer accepted for drawing attention to the similarities with CV and "dynamic range". On the price-discount formula ... not apropos since it's naturally asymmetric (list price is the reference point).